# Adding new keys to dictionary with shelve

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, set, shelve

I'm trying to add new name to file["users"], 'file' is a shelve object (if that's what it is called),
and  update file["homes"]
file["users"] is a set
and file["homes"] is a dictionary

```
import shelve

file = shelve.open("test")

file["users"] = {"user1", "user2", "user3", "user4"}
file["homes"] = {"user1" : "/user1", "user2" : "/user2",
             "user3" : "/user3", "user4" : "/"}

print("enter new user name to add")
username = input()
file["users"].add(username) #this does not work
print(file["users"])

file["homes"][username] = "/" + username #this does not work
print(file["homes"])
file.close
```

but this code does not do that
I have tried set.union, set.update, set.add

```
file["users"] = file["users"].union[{username}] #only this works
```

but don't know if it is correct way to do that.

Comment: i'm trying to add new (key, value) to a dictionary opened with shelve

Answer (score 0):

do `file = shelve.open("test", writeback = True)` and it will work